# Convert Python Dictionary To .csv file

Tags: python

I want to Convert my python Dictionary to .csv file where Dictionary consists of "keywordvalue":[listofdata] with that said i want my csv file to look in such way that keyword value is column in csv file and data inside list will stay in that column corresponding to the key.
Example -->

```
my_dict={"date":['11/2/19','3/11/20'],"name":['dexter','morgan']
```

CSV_file output -->

```
date,name
'11/2/19','dexter'
'3/11/20','morgan'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to munge your dict a bit, but something like this would work:

```
import csv

field_names = ['date', 'name']

my_dict={"date":['11/2/19','3/11/20'],"name":['dexter','morgan']}

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    rows = zip(*[my_dict[name] for name in field_names])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

This use of `zip` is a common idiom for "transposing", so:

```
zip(*[my_dict[name] for name in field_names])
```

So, for example:

```
In [2]: my_dict={"date":['11/2/19','3/11/20'],"name":['dexter','morgan']}

In [2]: field_names = ['date', 'name']

In [3]: list(zip(*[my_dict[name] for name in field_names]))
Out[3]: [('11/2/19', 'dexter'), ('3/11/20', 'morgan')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use csv module:

```
import csv

field_names = ['Date', 'Name']

my_dict=[{"date":'11/2/19',"name":'dexter'}, {"date":'3/11/20',"name":'morgan'}]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = field_names) 
    writer.writeheader() 
    writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

for more information check:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file/

Comment: In that document it's list of dictionaries. its like my_dict = [{dict1},{dict2},{dict3}]

Comment: This will not work, each row has to be a dict

Comment: Yes I think we should first change **dictionary with list values** to **list of dictionaries**